# Filtering column in excel with two or more criteria using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I want to filter a column in excel with two or more criteria. The syntax allows up to two criteria. I used array concept that didn't work. Help me on this. Thank you.

The syntax is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter.aspx)

My code is below

```
Range.AutoFilter(Feild:1,Criteria1:"USD", Operator: XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr,Criteria2:"HKD");
```

Answer (score 1):

mmm This word is wrong in your code `Feild`

Try this:

For two criteria:

```
Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "=USD", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=HKD"
```

Multiple Criteria:

```
Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= Array("USD", "HKD", "INR"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: i want to filter using 3 criteria. for example USD, HKD and INR

Comment: Oh I see, in that case put all your criteria into an array and change the Operator.

Comment: @virtualdvid: nice one! Had a doubt. Will this work something like this: `Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:>= Array(10, 13, 17), Operator:=xlFilterValues` ?. I want the cells in the column to be greater or equal to one of the integers in this array.